# How to keep my website available in two country and restrict rest?

Tags: geotargeting, country-specific

I am a non tech guy , looking for a solution to limit the access of my wp website to people from two countries only.  I'm using easywp.

want it to be accessible to only one/two countries for two reasons, first the content is specific to one country only, second it can't be protected from copying in other countries.